# Install4j Linux application

Tags: java, linux, startup, install4j

I'm developing an install4j application for multiple platforms. At the  moment I want the application to run at start up of the computer in linux. I have already set it to run at startup on Windows and OS X. The application has GUI. How can i set this in install4j?

Comment: Wait, I just read it has a GUI. So you want to start it automatically not when the computer starts but when a given user logs in?

Comment: The idea is the application to be available from the system tray when the user logs in. From the tray the user can open the application window.

Comment: install4j has no support for auto-start items of Linux desktop environments. You would have to implement the necessary modifications for the target DE yourself.

Comment: Well i just done that before some time and ya its making work for windows but its not having support for Linux. so it can not work for ubuntu.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379563/putting-java-application-on-start-up-while-creating-set-up-fine-in-install4j