# Putting Java Application on Start up While Creating Set up fine in Install4j

Tags: java, swing, startup, install4j

I have One java Desktop application and i am making build for the Diff Plate Forms I am using install4j.

My Question is that is it possible to make some settings while Creating build and i want to add that build in start Up of Windows. everytime when user Install that application that has to added in startuo Auto.

How to do it using any installer?

i can do it by putting manual on start up folder but i want to make it auto.

Comment: Short answer, yes, long answer [read the docs](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/extending/api.html) :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer make it short. :P but using installer??

Comment: Yes, Install4J provides a means for you to extend it's functionality via it's own API functionality, as detailed in the docs

Comment: @MadProgrammer Brother that means it will be in external luncher?

Comment: No, it means you provide a custom action/screen/component which is executed by the installer

Comment: @MadProgrammer so instead of splash Screen i need to provide custom. but for that i need to copy api jar to my class path?

Comment: I have no idea. I've not used Install4J before, but I would have thought that it would bundle all it's required resources into a single file, depending on the platform

Comment: ya its bundling that but its giving single excusable jar with external libs but will it be possible using other installer whatever installer that u have used?

Comment: @MadProgrammer http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/steps/installerGui/availableActions.html this is what u talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install4j has a "Add a startup executable on Windows and OS X" action that you can use for that purpose.

Comment: at which stage it must be at step:4 installer ? is it?

Comment: +1 for your response but please still m not having idea can u just explain it little bit more?

Comment: Just tell me one thing which stage it occurs.?

Comment: Yes, on the Installer->Screens & Actions step, you look for the "Installation" screen in your installer and click on the "Add" button. Then you can search for this action.

Comment: dude what i suppose to put entry name in that?

Comment: M not able to do that :(

Comment: Well great ans but still it happens only for Windows is any other way to make it for ubuntu too??

Comment: No, as of 5.1.12, install4j does not support this functionality for Linux.

Comment: then older version Do support this?

Comment: No, I'm just writing the version number, so that future visitors of this page will see what version I was talking about.

Comment: so any other installer have this facilities to add application on start up?